# JPA query - how to mix arbitrary query strings and CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I need to perform a query of the form

```
SELECT dontcare FROM Bar b WHERE x = y AND expr
```

- x is the name of any field in Bar, y is a specific value. These come via a Servlet and cannot be trusted.
- expr is a project specific filter to change the scope of the query involving other fields - this is trusted and comes from a configuration file and could be quite complex.

An unsafe approach would be

```
String qStr = "SELECT foo FROM Bar b WHERE " + x " = " + y " AND " + expr
```

However x and y are not trusted source so leaves open to injection attack. I've found CriteriaBuilder, and made a programmatic build of the "x = y" part that works fine, but cannot find how to append the "AND expr".

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaBuilder<Bar> q = cb.createQuery(Foo.class);
Root<Bar> root = q.from(Bar.class);
Predicate p1 = cb.equals(root.get(x), y);
Predicate p2 = <====== help needed here, how can I use expr
q.where(cb.and(p1, p2));
Query query = em.createQuery(q);
```

Any ideas? I've spent a good amount of time looking through tutorials and the javadocs for Expression, Predicate, Query etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the criteria api you can create conjunctions, which contain a number of predicates that all have to be true.

If you want OR, you can use disjunctions.

something like:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Product.class);
Conjunction conjunction = Restrictions.conjunction();
conjunction.add(Restrictions.isNull("location"));
conjunction.add(Restrictions.eq("location", ""));
crit.add(conjunction);
```

Comment: Is that a hibernate rather than JPA thing? I can't find the classes Restrictions or Conjunction...

Comment: yes, you're right, but I am under the impression it's similar for JPA; check out these 2 links for more info: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/logical http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/criteria/CriteriaBuilder apparantly CriteriaBuilder has methods conjunction() and disjunction()

Comment: I think you can use methods and(Predicate... restrictions) and or(Predicate... restrictions) from CriteriaBuilder

Comment: Thank you, I've checked them out, but still can't find anything that converts a string like "b.z = 1 AND (b.f =2 OR b.f = 3)" into a form usable with CriteriaBuilder ...

Comment: Owkee, I think I understand your question now. Instead of just pasting strings together or using the Criteria api, I think you can do what you want by using javax.persistence.Query and the method setParameter(java.lang.String name, java.lang.Object value); make the queryString, append your configured expression, then set the parameter from the first part of your query. With CriteriaBuilder I don't think you can do what you want.

Comment: OK, thanks. Seems shame there isn't a public API for building queries from Strings, as there must be something internally that does it! I'll accept your answer anyway.